# var = Variable + 'String'

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, jquery-load

I'm trying to dynamically include a text file into my page using jQuery, but I can't seem to get it to work with a variable as the filepath. I tried with just title.txt instead of passing a variable and it worked, but $title + '.txt' didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**Works:**

```
$(function () {  
    $("#list").load('test.txt');
});
```

**Attempt 1:**

```
$(function () {
    var $title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML,
        $url = $title + '.txt';

    $("#list").load($url);
});
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$(function () {
    var $title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML,
        $ext = '.txt',
        $url = $title + $ext;

    $("#list").load($url);
});
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
$(function () {
    var $title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML,

    $("#list").load($title + '.txt');
});
```

Comment: What is the response of each attempt?

Comment: What does `console.log($url);` return? (for attempts 1 and 2)

Comment: I can't believe that `$("#list").load(test.txt);` works. Did you mean `$("#list").load("test.txt");`, or do you really have an object like `var test = {txt: "…some url…"};`?

Comment: Your are most likely not passing the correct value to `load`. There is not much you can do wrong with variables and concatenation. `var foo = ...;` creates and assigns to a variables `foo + 'abc'` concatenates `'abc'` to `foo`. You are already doing that, so the value must be wrong. Solution: Make sure you pass the correct value.

Comment: Please show us your html markup. Does `$title` actually contain the expected value? Are there any whitespaces maybe?

Comment: And last question, are you working locally?

Comment: @Bergi : corrected with quotes around the filename.

Comment: I'm working on localhost with an AMP stack.

Comment: Did you try to pass a function that returns an url?

Comment: If you `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML)` I'm sure that you will not be getting "test". What are you getting?

Comment: The log is showing the $url, but it disregards everything after the space. Can I add %20 in the spaces to make it work?

Comment: @Jameel yes, that should work.

Comment: @jcuenod I'm not getting anything for it at all

Comment: @Jameel but that line is what you are populating `$title` with. If it's empty, it's not going to find your file

Comment: It works for some reason for $url though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, per comment in chat:

```
$(function () {
    var $title = encodeURI( $('title').text() ), 
        $url = $title + '.txt';

    $("#list").load($url);
});
```

Comment: Curiosity: what else will encodeURI change other than the spaces to %20? I'm dealing with more than 100 files.

Comment: Nevermind, filenames are good as long as they don't have:

", / ? : @ & = + $ #"

+1 for a better solution to account for potential characters in the page title.

Comment: @Jameel if they potentially have those characters, use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `encodeURI`. :)

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the spaces in the file name. Used replace() to convert spaces to %20.

```
$(function () {
    var $title = $(document).attr('title'),
        $ext = '.txt',
        $url = $title + $ext,
        $cleanurl = $url.replace(/\s/g,"%20");

    $("#list").load($cleanurl);

});
```